# Refused to set unsafe header "Date" AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am not able to add Date in the header,  every time I add the date I get the error. ***Refused to set unsafe header "Date"***

This is My code;

```
 $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https:......',
      data: message,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                'XReference':reference,                                  
                                'Authorization':auth,
                                'Date':unixtimestamp                                 

       }
 })
```

Comment: Since XmlHttpRequest doesn't allow the `Date` header to be set, could you use a custom header of a different name for your purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beneath `$http` it uses [XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and `XmlHttpRequest` isn't allowed to set the `Date` header as per the [standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method).

Step 5 states:

> Terminate these steps if header is a case-insensitive match for one of
>   the following headers...

and `Date` is included in that list.

It seems like some browsers allow it and others do not.

Comment: So how can I insert it if it is compulsory?

Comment: @KelvinMuli You can't - those headers are automatically set by the browser or disabled.

Comment: `some browsers allow it and others do not.`  Which browsers allow it?  the XHR spec says "don't do this."  So it would be a violation.  Maybe older versions I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing **"Date"** to **"Request-Date"**

Answer (score 0):

Browsers don't allow you to set the date header in AJAX requests. According to the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader()-method):

> Terminate these steps if header is a case-insensitive match for one of the following headers:
>
> - ...
> - Date
> - ...

Comment: latest URL for the spec is: https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-setrequestheader%28%29-method